# DisplayLink LT1421 and Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, lenovo, displaylink

I have a problem with installing my display Lenovo LT1421 on Ubuntu. I tried to install original driver (http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) according to manual on DisplayLink website (http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/615714-how-to-install-displaylink-software#ubuntu) but it wont work. It only shows black screen. Apt-get update, dist-upgrade and upgrade was already done. I have kernel 3.19.0-51-generic and version 14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 22:02:58 UTC 2016.

xrandr --listproviders shows this:

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x199 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

Display is visible in lsusb and dmesg shows this:

```
[  385.035567] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  385.391498] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=03e0
[  385.391505] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  385.391507] usb 1-1: Product: Lenovo LT1421 wide
[  385.391509] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[  385.391511] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 6V9CHDG9
[  385.399108] [drm] vendor descriptor length:17 data:17 5f 01 00 15 05 00 01 03 00 04
[  385.792728] udl 1-1:1.0: fb3: udldrmfb frame buffer device
[  385.792734] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[  385.792736] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[  385.792739] [drm] Initialized udl on minor 3
[  385.831167] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[  385.832991] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[  385.840739] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[  386.262437] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[  386.263054] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[  386.263538] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[  386.668883] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[  388.880960] [D] evdi_painter_connect (dev=2) Connected with ffff88007919c000
[  388.881025] [D] evdi_painter_connect (dev=2) Edid (3 bytes): 00 ff ff
[  388.881033] [D] evdi_detect (dev=2) Painter is connected
[  389.298588] [D] evdi_detect (dev=2) Painter is connected
[  389.299002] [D] evdi_detect (dev=2) Painter is connected
[  389.299005] [D] evdi_painter_get_edid (dev=2) 00 ff ff
```

I tried to install it by an old way: install xserver-xorg-video-displaylink but it says that this package is no more available. That sounds logic because it should be already in kernel, but...

I am totally trapped with this issue.

Is there any other way or some trick?

Thanks a lot for any response!

EDIT1: Maybe it is good to say, that I am trying it on virtualized Linux (using VMware).

Answer (score 0):

***TL;DR:*** First try with [an officially backported kernel from 16.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_-_Trusty_Tahr) and the latest driver version.

You're running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty and 3.19 is [the kernel version used in Vivid](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta), so I am guessing you installed the officially backported version through the package `linux-generic-lts-vivid`.

<sup>That's the usually the best way to get a Vivid kernel version on Trusty, though I am not sure that particular version is available in this way. If you installed it some other way, then the best way to proceed might depend on how you installed it and might involve uninstalling it before proceeding to install another version.</sup>

<sup>If you installed kernel 3.19 by using a package meant for Vivid, or it is an upstream (mainline) kernel that you built and installed yourself, then I recommend uninstalling it (or at leat not using it) and proceeding with kernels that are both more recent (higher version number) and officially provided for your Ubuntu release.</sup>

If you want to use a kernel from Vivid and you didn't also install `xserver-xorg-lts-vivid` and (since you're using VMware and presumably want its virtual display to work too) `xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid`, I suggest trying that to see if it fixes the problem.

Otherwise I recommend seeing if the backported kernel from Xenial fixes the problem. For a desktop system [the way **LTSEnablementStack** recommends](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_-_Trusty_Tahr) to install it is to run:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

You'll have to reinstall the driver for the new kernel. First, **make sure you have the latest version**, unless you are deliberately using an earlier version. As of this writing, [the latest version is 1.3.54](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=993). (If you are currently using an earlier version, then perhaps just upgrading could fix the problem.)

Though it is not the same problem as this--you've successfully installed the driver, it just doesn't work--the related question **[failed to build evdi installing displaylink drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938580/failed-to-build-evdi-installing-displaylink-drivers)** might be helpful to you, or to others who find this question by searching.

If the Xenial kernel doesn't help, then further troubleshooting will be necessary. Since this is in a virtual machine, I suggest trying Ubuntu 16.04:

- You could create a separate virtual machine, installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and seeing if it works on that.
- Or you could have VMware take a snapshot of your Ubuntu 14.04 LTS virtual machine, then upgrade it to 16.04 LTS. (You can always roll back by restoring the snapshot.)

If this works, and you're willing to use 16.04, then you have your solution. If it doesn't work, or does but you must use 14.04, then this will still have provided potentially valuable information that may help lead to a solution.