# Failed to build EVDI installink displaylink drivers (even though already in 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, dell, displaylink

I am having a similar problem to [this post: Failed to build EVDI installing dispalylink drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938580/failed-to-build-evdi-installing-displaylink-drivers)
(when installing a Dell Adapter DA100)

as in fact my output is

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-1.3.54.run 
[sudo] password di myname: 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 1.3.54  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 1.3.54 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
ERROR (code 3): Failed to build evdi/1.3.54. Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.3.54/build/make.log for details..
```

and the funny thing is that I cannot access the `make.log` file. If I try to `cd` there I get `denied access` in the `build` folder where the `make.log` file should be. As you can see from above my Ubuntu is `16.04.2` so I guess I don't need to upgrade the OS.

Comment: does the directory `/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.3.54/build/` exist and with what permissions? `sudo ls -l /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.3.54/build/make.log`). I guess the `build` directory is removed if the build is successful (I don't have it on my system), but could be as simple as your personal user doesn't have read permissions.

Comment: @mgor that's the output of your command:

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3058 ago  8 11:20 /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.3.54/build/make.log

Comment: This is for the same problem as your other question [Failed to build EVDI installing dispalylink driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944663/failed-to-build-evdi-installing-dispalylink-driver), right? Assuming that is the case, we should close this as a duplicate so people who find this know to go there and so continued work on the problem can be consolidated there.